# iPad calendar entry disappears after edit

Tags: ios, icloud, calendar

I've been having a strange issue with future calendar entries disappearing for a while. I'm finally able to reproduce the problem. I have an iPad mini running iOS 9.3.5 (newest version it supports).

When I click on a link such as [this](http://events.wheatonlibrary.org/evanced/lib/eventsignup.asp?ID=15508&rts=&disptype=&ret=eventcalendar.asp&pointer=&returnToSearch=&num=0&ad=&dt=mo&mo=9/1/2018&df=calendar&EventType=ALL&Lib=&AgeGroup=ALL&LangType=0&WindowMode=&noheader=&lad=&pub=1&nopub=&page=&pgdisp=) one and select download to calendar it prompts me to add it to my calendar. After adding it, the entry appears on my calendar as expected.

If I then go into calendar, tap on the event, edit, change the reminder alert time, and tap done, the entry disappears from the calendar. I can reproduce this every time. One clue I noticed is that if I turn off iCloud for the calendar before I add the entry the problem does not occur.

It only happens when creating the invite via a link.  Events added manually never have this problem.  I've tried toggling iCloud on/off.  That didn't bring it back.  I also verified that I am not over my iCloud disk quota.  Any idea what is going on?